# "Whirlpool" Adjuncts

Tags: adjuncts

We brewed bear-flavored's Heady Topper clone last weekend, and the beer has just over 1# of hops in it (5 gallon) All of the hops are added at flameout and whirlpool (it actually doesn't even call for bittering hops, but does have hop extract @ 90 minutes).

It got me thinking, when I brew my wit, I add about a cup of fresh citrus zest, crushed Indian Coriander, and chamomile at flameout. My question is, would it make more sense to add these around 180* during chilling? The wit smells UNBELIEVABLE when it is chilling, but if I am smelling it then, that means its no longer in the beer.  The last two I have had to 'dry adjunct' by throwing in post-fermentation additions of zest and chamomile.

Comment: How did the "dry adjuncts" compare to throwing them in the boil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea to me. The temperature is high enough to sanitize the ingredients being added, yet lower than boiling so not all the delicate volatile aromatics are driven off.

You might also consider trying this with a hopback and a plate or counterflow chiller. The theory is that since the hopback and chiller are sealed, any volatiles that are released are re-absorbed when the wort is chilled immediately to pitching temperature.